# How to do simple math by reading each line of two text files and save result to another text file in VB.Net or C#?

Tags: vb.net

I have two text files (myFile1.TXT and myFile2.TXT) of the same size with comma delimited values as follows:

In myFile1.TXT, I have the following:

1, 19, 21, 1
2, 15, 21, 1
3, 15, 21, 1
4, 22, 21, 1
...

In myFile2, I have the following:

1, 5, 1, 0.5
2, 3, 2, 1
3, 3, 1, 0.5
4, 1, 1, 0.2
...

What I would like is to read the values of every line of the three columns of MyFile2.TXT (col2, col3, and col4) and subtract this sum from the corresponding line of the 2nd column of myFile1.TXT (from col2).  The result will be saved in another file, say myResult.TXT, which will have values as follows (with only three columns, because the first column in myFile1.TXT and myFile2.TXT indicate records):

12.5, 21, 1
9, 21, 1
7.5, 21, 1
19.8, 21, 1
...

I tried with the following code but it works only for the first line:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ColumnCount

            'Check if myFile1.TXT exists
            If New FileInfo(myFile1.TXT).Exists Then
                String1 = srData1.ReadLine()   'Read 1 line from a file
                Dim Values1() As String = String1.Split(",") 'split values in a comma separated line
                'Read and get values from myFile1.TXT
                A1(i) = Values1(1) '
                B1(i) = Values1(2)
                C1(i) = Values1(3)

                'Check if the second file exists (because this file may not exist). We do the operation only if this file exists

                If New FileInfo(myFile2.TXT).Exists Then
                    String2 = srData2.ReadLine()   'Read 1 line from a file
                    Dim Values2() As String = String2.Split(",") '
                    'Read and get values from myFile2.TXT
                    A2(i) = Values2(1) '
                    B2(i) = Values2(2)
                    C2(i) = Values2(3)

                End If
                For r As Integer = 0 To RowCount - 1

                    Result(r) = A1(r) - A2(r) - B2(r) - C2(r)1
                    swNetFlow.WriteLine(Result(r) & ", " & B1(r) & ", " & C1(r))

                Next

            End If
        Next
```

But I get only the following:

12.5, 21, 1
0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0

As you can see, it writes zero's on the remaining lines.  Can anyone help me fix this to get it work?

Comment: Am I correct in guessing that `ColumnCount` is meant to be the number of *rows* in the file and `RowCount` is the number of *columns*?

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  The do loop worked perfectly. In the For .. Next, ColumnCount and RowCount meant to be for columns and rows. I replace the code with the For with the Do loop now, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop for you ReadLine so that it will read  the next line of the text file after it reads the first line. Try using a "for" or "while" loop. 
-Hope this helps.